# Почему выводится None в классе - потомке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name,
            cuisine_type):

        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number = 0

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print("The name of the restaurant:")
        print(self.restaurant_name.title())
        print("Cuisine type in this restaurant is:")
        print(self.cuisine_type.title())

    def set_number_served(self, number_seats):
        self.number = number_seats

    def number_served(self):
        print(" It is the number of reserved seats:")
        print("\t\t" + str(self.number))

    def increment_number_served(self, number_visitors):
        print("The number of served visitors per day:")
        print("\t\t" + str(number_visitors))

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print("The restaurant is open!")


data_restaurant = Restaurant("'sushi-bar'", "'japanese cuisine'")
data_restaurant.describe_restaurant()
data_restaurant.set_number_served(2)
data_restaurant.number_served()
data_restaurant.increment_number_served(29)
print( )
data_restaurant.open_restaurant()

print("\n")
print("-----------------------------------------------")

restaurant = Restaurant("'live food'", "'raw food diet'")
restaurant.describe_restaurant()
restaurant.set_number_served(5)
restaurant.number_served()
restaurant.increment_number_served(18)
print( )
restaurant.open_restaurant()
print("\n\n")
print("----------------------------------------------")


class IceCream(Restaurant):
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)

    def flavors(self, ingredients=['limon', 'vanilla', 'chocolate', 'mango']):
        print("We have follow ice creams:")
        print( )
        print(ingredients)

my_icecream = IceCream("'funny ice'", "'ice cream restaurant'")
print(my_icecream.describe_restaurant())
my_icecream.flavors()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустил ваш код и там вывело много строк, но среди них было:

```
...
Cuisine type in this restaurant is:
'Ice Cream Restaurant'
None
...
We have follow ice creams:
```

Думаю, вас именно строка интересовала.

А причина в том, что у вас выводится:

```
print(my_icecream.describe_restaurant())
```

Метод `describe_restaurant` ничего не возвращает явно, поэтому из него вернется `None`

Comment: Но ведь в функции - родителе все выводиться корректно, без None?

Answer (score 0):

Для IceCream вы делаете так:

```
print(my_icecream.describe_restaurant())
```

А для объектов родительского класса так:

```
restaurant.describe_restaurant()
```

Видите разницу? В одном случае вы просты вызываете метод, а во втором делает print результата для этого метода.

И в том, и в другом случае метод выполняется, печатает информацию о ресторане, и возвращает None.

Вот только в одном случае с этим None больше уже ничего не происходит, а во втором случае print выводит его вам.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь понятно)